# Update list of bit using while loop in python

Tags: python, list, binary

I have a list of bit. The problem is I need to update the value of the bit according to the new bit that I have. This is the example of my code:

```
count=1
cycle=3
bit_list = ['1','0','1','0']
new_bit=['1','0','1']
no=''.join(bit_list)
bit=''.join(new_bit)

while (count<=cycle):
    for b in no:
        print (b)
    print ("end of cycle", count)
    def bin_add(*args): return bin(sum(int(x, 2) for x in args))[2:]
    update=bin_add(no,bit)
    count=count+1
print ("updated list",update)
```

I need the following output:

```
1
0
1
0
updated list 1011  #1010 + 1
end of cycle 1
1
0
1
1
updated list 1011  #1011 + 0
end of cycle 2
1
0
1
1
updated list 1100   #1011 + 1
end of cycle 3
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: what is problem statement it is not clear, at which position you want to append the new bit

Comment: For each cycle, I need to update the bit list based on the new bit using bit addition function. For example, at the 1st cycle 1010 + 1= 1011, 2nd cycle 1011+0=1011 and 3rd cycle 1011+1=1100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the output to be in the variable `update` and yet your loop keeps using `no` and `bit` for operations, so `update` doesn't evolve after each iteration. You should also add only the bit of the current index to the output. You should also output your "end of cycle" messages at.. the end of the iteration, not in the beginning:

```
count=1
cycle=3
bit_list = ['1','0','1','0']
new_bit=['1','0','1']
no=''.join(bit_list)
bit=''.join(new_bit)
while (count<=cycle):
    def bin_add(*args): return bin(sum(int(x, 2) for x in args))[2:]
    no=bin_add(no,bit[count - 1])
    for b in no:
        print (b)
    print ("end of cycle", count)
    count=count+1
print ("updated list",no)
```

This outputs:

```
1
0
1
1
end of cycle 1
1
0
1
1
end of cycle 2
1
1
0
0
end of cycle 3
updated list 1100
```